# Search in specific Discussion Board

Tags: search

I have a site in SharePoint 2013, with multiples Discussions Board, I need to search only inside this one, not in all boards.
"conversationresults.aspx?u={contexturl}" search inside every discussion board.

There is some way to filter only the discussion board that I want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question.

I just created a new "Result Source", and created a filter to just get the specific list:

```
{?{searchTerms} ListID:{XXXXXX-XXXXX-LISTID}  (contentclass:STS_ListItem OR IsDocument:True)}
```

The **{?** at the beginning means that the result will show only after I search, and contentclass only documents and list items.

In result properties I changed to use the result source that I've created.

Hope this help someone else!

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways, you need to experiment a bit. The one that comes to mind easily is using a Path modifier like "Path:URL Path to the board". You can also use Site, Web and other modifiers depending on how your Farm is configured.